# PHP MVC Framework + Generate KML file

Tags: php, kml

I implemented a basic mvc framework in php. The problem is that when I want to create a dynamic kml file not open, because the file at the start of blank spaces are generated. If I do it from any file (not the framework), it works correctly.

Link :localhost/Radio/index/asset

Controller : indexController.php
method : asset()

code:

```
public function asset() {

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');



    $kmlOutput = $dom->saveXML();
    $kmlOutput = trim($kmlOutput);              
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="myfilename.kml"');
    echo  $kmlOutput;

}
```

error in Google Earth :

[image: error]

kml generate:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blanks at the beginning of the output are often caused by newlines behind the closing [php tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php).

```
<?php¶
¶
// Some code here¶
¶
?>¶
¶
```

Anything outside of `<?php ?>` as directly seen as output. Therefor, you should never use the closing tag in library files.

To [quote Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.php-file-formatting.html):

> For files that contain only PHP code, the closing tag ("?>") is never
>   permitted. It is not required by PHP, and omitting it´ prevents the
>   accidental injection of trailing white space into the response.

Comment: Yes, you right. Thanks for your help. Every day you learn something new. Displaying the documentation, I found another solution for people like me careless: ob_clean ();